# Out-of-Process COM Server - .NET Core/.NET

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5

I know that out-of-process COM servers are not supported in .NET Core/.NET, but there are ways of getting them done as demonstrated by [this Microsoft code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/samples/out-of-process-com-server/).

However, I find the code quite confusing and not clear at all in regards to what exactly is needed.

I currently have a working as an in-process COM server in .NET 5 and all I needed to do was:

- Import the COM object
- Create my implementation with `[ComVisible(true)]`
- Add `<EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>` to the .csproj file
- Register the `<projectName>.comhost.dll` file produced when compiling with `regsvr32.exe`

In other words, I didn't need an IDL file or to use MIDL to compile it into a type library or anything alike.

Now trying to turn this already working in-process COM server into an out-of-process and I'm not really sure where to begin. Do I all of a sudden need an IDL file or a type library? Looking at the code from the sample above they clearly require a tlb file to do the COM server registration.

So what exactly is required to create an out-of-process COM server for an existing already registered COM interface in .NET Core/.NET? Is an IDL file/type library file still needed? If not, how would you register the server?

Any code examples would be hugely appreciated as well.

Comment: No built-in support for the type library generation - more info in the link provided.

Comment: It appears many of us are searching for the answer to this. I have my own similar question posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71492604/how-do-i-instantiate-a-comvisible-class-in-a-net-core-assembly-from-net-framew?noredirect=1#comment126376588_71492604. For out of process we need to create a type library, but nobody seems to know how.