# How to instantiate a ComVisible class in a .NET Core assembly from .NET Framework application?

Tags: c#, .net-5, com-interop, .net-framework-version, regfreecom

We have a software product that is currently released that is a **.NET Framework 4.7.2** application (the "legacy" app). The *legacy* client-server implementation is built on *System.Runtime.Remoting*, which is not supported in **.NET 5** and later, so the **.NET 5** implementation is **gRPC**.

It is necessary to instantiate each of the two COM servers in turn because the legacy and the .NET 5 COM servers can only connect to the comm (not COM) server application that implements the same communications framework, which are *System.Runtime.Remoting* and *gRPC*, respectively.

The COM servers are used by third party applications to interface with the comm server application, so I am currently working on creating a static class that returns the interface from the COM server that can connect to the currently running instance of the comm server.

I have a **.NET 5** WPF implementation of the product almost complete, but I've hit a roadblock in that, I am unable to register the .NET COM server.

I found these two articles:
[Exposing .NET Core Components to COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com)
[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/installer/issues/5851)

I have now been able to:

### Create a Type Library

I found a comment from @SimonMourier suggesting copying the .NET 5 COM server code into a .NET Framework project and use RegAsm to export the type library to be used in the .NET 5 project. The type library was added to the .NET 5 COM server project folder and "" was added to an ItemGroup in the .csproj file per the first referenced article.

### Register the .NET 5 COM server

This required using the **"dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Debug"** command in the project folder from the *Visual Studio Developer Command Line*. I was then able to use **regsvr32** to register the *WinCalRemoting.comhost.dll* in the "*bin\Debug\net5.0\win-x64\publish*" project directory.

### Create an Instance of the COM Class

After registering the COM server, I am now able to create an instance of the COM class, but haven't been successful at getting the interface from it:

```
    public static IWinCalClient LoadCompatibleRemotingClient(bool useClientEventWindow, string serverName, int serverPort, bool connectToServer = true)
    {
        UseClientEventWindow = useClientEventWindow;
        WinCalServerName = serverName;
        WinCalServerPort = serverPort;
        ClassIdList = new Guid[]
        {
            LegacyWinCalClientClsId, // CAN'T GET INTERFACE FROM THIS COM SERVER
            //WinCal5ClientClsId // THE .NET 5 COM SERVER WORKS
        };

        if (RemotingClassObject != null)
        {
            UnloadClient();
        }

        foreach (Guid clsId in ClassIdList)
        {
            try
            {
                RemotingClassObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(clsId, true));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (RemotingClassObject != null)
            {
                RemotingInterface = (IWinCalClient)RemotingClassObject;

                if (RemotingInterface == null)
                {
                    UnloadClient();
                    continue;
                }

                if (CanClientConnect(_RemotingInterface, connectToServer))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (Marshal.IsComObject(RemotingClassObject))
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(RemotingClassObject);
            }

            RemotingClassObject = null;
        }

        return RemotingInterface;
    }
```

### Update on the exception

After correcting the "bitness" of the test COM Client application that @SimonMourier clued me to, I am able to get the interface from the .NET 5 COM server. I have updated the code from the method.

**HOWEVER**, I'm now struggling with getting the interface from the **.NET Framework COM server** in the same way I get it from the .NET 5 COM server. I successfully register it using **RegAsm.exe**, but I get the following exception:
**System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'CMI.WinCalRemoting.cWinCalClient' to type 'CMI.WinCalRemoting.IWinCalClient'.'**.

I've done an exhaustive search to try to find out how to fix the *.NET Framework* COM project so that it can be used in the same way that the *.NET 5* COM server is used so that it doesn't matter whether the COM client is a .NET Framework or a .NET Core assembly.

I added a **.NET Framework COM server project** to the shared directory below to replicate what I'm seeing. With the *.NET Framework* COM server.

I also switched the test application to be 32-bit to replicate how our sister application will be using the COM servers.

All of the projects are located here:
[.NET 5 COM Interop](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jxiw40ikgoi47fv/AAAyELYXdflud1tRxsZGSIhza?dl=0)

### Unable to Add .NET Framework COM Type Library Reference

For a *.NET Framework* client assembly, I've attempted to add a reference to the *.NET Framework* COM server that was registered with *regasm.exe*, but that fails with the following message:
[image: Try to Add Project Reference for .NET Framework COM Assembly]

Comment: Your question is far from being clear. Why do you want to use LoadFile at all to instantiate a COM server? That's not how it's supposed to work (GetType fails because "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, [...] The system cannot find the file specified" which is why you shouldn't use LoadFile). I've looked at the sample but they are obviously broken (for example code looks for WinCalRemoting.cWinCalClient and other project namespace is CMI.WinCalRemoting.cWinCalClient, names have been changed, etc.).

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to use COM to interface between two .NET assemblies (of different .NET versions), am I understanding that correctly? If so, why do you need to do that?

Comment: Because the COM servers uses different communication architecture, so depending on which communication server (not COM server) is currently running (legacy or .NET 5 gRPC ),  the sister app needs to get the compatible COM server.

Comment: @StayOnTarget, I actually think I'll use different class IDs now and instantiate each to check for compatibility, but I still di t know how to create a type lib for the .NET 5 COM server.

Comment: I'm sorry if you felt offended by my question, and yes, I'm fully aware of how to do COM communication between .NET framework and .NET Core, but if you need help, then provide what's needed to be helped. You will not get help if your question is not clear and your sample code is incorrect (have you even tested it as you posted it?).

Comment: I have changed the CLSID of the .NET 5 COM server and now attempt to instantiate each COM server until one of them can connect to the running comm (not COM) server. Since I don't know how to create a Type Library, it won't work.

Comment: @JeffH I suggest you add directly to your question the most minimal example you can come up with that demonstrates the issue. This will make the Q much more accessible and understandable to anyone reading it. And as far as it goes, that's often a really good exercise in itself to try and narrow down the problem.

Comment: @StayOnTarget good suggestion. I've been whittling it down and have updated the test solutions. I will be posting an update.

Comment: @SimonMourier, cudos to you for the idea I used for creating a type library for the .NET 5 COM server. I mention it in my revised post.

Comment: COM in .net framework is a bad smell and even worse in .net core. i admit that i don't know much about COM

Comment: @LeiYang, I agree, but I have no choice given the fact that our sister app needs to be able to use both a .NET Framework implementation and a .NET 5 implementation from a .NET Framework app.

Comment: First thing is making sure your client project uses the same bitness as the server. I had to update your client to uncheck "prefer-32 bit" as the server was registered for x64. Once that worked (for some reason it already worked for you) and since you defined IWinCalClient in both projects (why not), you don't need to do `GetType().GetInterface("CMI.WinCalRemoting.IWinCalClient")`, just cast the object using local interface definition `_RemotingInterface = (IWinCalClient)o` and now it works.

Comment: @SimonMourier, thanks VERY much for bringing that to my attention! Yes, that worked. I'm now going to import the type lib into the client app so I don't have to define it. This, of course would be the preferred method.

Comment: I had a very similar problem recently where I had to add a .net 6 DLL into MS Access and also came accross the links you gave. I ended up creating a new type library (TLB-file) and added that as reference to the client via Visual Studio. Visual Studio created a interop.dll-file. Have you tried that / are you still on that problem?

Comment: Hi, @Jan, I managed to do the same thing for the .net 5 COM server. The frustrating thing is that, apparently it isn't possible to create a true COM server DLL for a .net framework DLL. Thanks for reaching out.

Comment: not sure if it helps but I just published my sample for the issues I had . maybe there's something in it for you https://github.com/janschreier/net6COMSample

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. that one works with MS Access, but not with asp.net for that I had to use a .exe-Server as is described in this example: https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/extensions/OutOfProcCOM