# How do I instantiate the COM interop Interface from a .NET Framework COM server DLL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, com-interop, .net-framework-version

We have two versions of a client-server software application product. One version is what is now considered "legacy", as it is implemented in **WinForms .NET Framework**, while the other is now implemented in **WPF .NET 5**.

Since 3rd party applications won't always know whether the "legacy" or "new" client-server application is running remotely, I have developed a *Client Loader* COM Interop class in the **.NET 5** client-server client assembly that a 3rd party client application can use to get the interface of the client-server client via **COM Interop**.

In addition, I need to support client-server client applications that are implemented n both **.NET Framework** and **.NET Core**.

After a LOT of searching and a bit of help from another StackOverflow user, I was able to successfully implement the **.NET 5 COM Interop server**. The information for that task can be found here: [How to create .NET 5 COM Interop server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71492604/how-to-instantiate-a-comvisible-class-in-a-net-core-assembly-from-net-framewor).

But although I've been successful at getting this to work for a **.NET 5 COM Interop server** and accessing the COM class interface from a **.NET Framework** assembly, I for the life of me cannot get it to work for the **.NET Framework COM Interop** assembly.

I have implemented the test solutions that can be found here: [COM Interop Test](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jxiw40ikgoi47fv/AAAyELYXdflud1tRxsZGSIhza?dl=0) with the following folders:

1. **TestDotNet5ComServer** - the .NET 5 COM Interop server solution
2. **TestDotNetFrameworkComServer** - the .NET Framework COM Interop solution
3. **ClientLoaderTestApp** - a .NET Framework client loader solution
4. **Com Interop Servers** - Both versions of the COM Interop Server assemblies

Here is the code for the Client Loader class:

```
public class WinCalRemoteClientLoader
{
    #region Properties
    private List<Guid> ClassIdList = new List<Guid>();

    #region WinCal Remoting Client COM Server CLSIDs
    /// <summary>
    /// .NET Framework COM Server CLSID
    /// </summary>
    private Guid LegacyWinCalClientClsId = new Guid("B4C1FE68-5D20-4557-9637-AF81F7F9831E");

    /// <summary>
    /// .NET 5 COM Server CLSID
    /// </summary>
    private Guid WinCal5ClientClsId = new Guid("BB2B4532-4EE4-4536-8EC5-17DF5377A13D");
    #endregion WinCal Remoting Client COM Server CLSIDs

    /// <summary>
    /// The singleton instantiated Remoting Client interface
    /// </summary>
    public object RemotingClassObject
    {
        get { return _RemotingClassObject; }

        private set { _RemotingClassObject = value; }
    }
    private object _RemotingClassObject = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// The remoting client interface
    /// </summary>
    public IWinCalClient RemotingInterface
    {
        get { return _RemotingInterface; }

        private set { _RemotingInterface = value; }
    }
    private IWinCalClient _RemotingInterface = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether or not the client should launch an event window
    /// </summary>
    public bool UseClientEventWindow
    {
        get { return _UseClientEventWindow; }

        set
        {
            _UseClientEventWindow = value;
        }
    }
    private bool _UseClientEventWindow = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// The server IP name
    /// </summary>
    public string WinCalServerName
    {
        get { return _WinCalServerName; }

        set
        {
            _WinCalServerName = value;
        }
    }
    private string _WinCalServerName = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// The WinCal server port number
    /// </summary>
    public int WinCalServerPort
    {
        get { return _WinCalServerPort; }

        set
        {
            _WinCalServerPort = value;
        }
    }
    private int _WinCalServerPort = 0;
    #endregion Properties

    #region Public Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// The Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public WinCalRemoteClientLoader()
    {
        ClassIdList.Add(LegacyWinCalClientClsId);
        ClassIdList.Add(WinCal5ClientClsId);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load a compatible WinCal remoting client
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="useClientEventWindow">Whether or not the client should launch an event window</param>
    /// <param name="serverName">The server IP name</param>
    /// <param name="serverPort">The WinCal server port number</param>
    /// <param name="connectToServer">If true, this method will return an interface that is already connected to the server</param>
    /// <returns>Either null or a connected IWinCalClient instance</returns>
    public IWinCalClient LoadCompatibleRemotingClient(bool useClientEventWindow, string serverName, int serverPort, bool connectToServer = true)
    {
        UseClientEventWindow = useClientEventWindow;
        WinCalServerName = serverName;
        WinCalServerPort = serverPort;

        RemotingInterface = TryLoadComServer(connectToServer);

        return RemotingInterface;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Release the COM object
    /// 
    /// If the WinCal Remoting client is still connected, the connection will be closed
    /// </summary>
    public void UnloadClient()
    {
        // Clean up the COM server, if it was created
        if (RemotingClassObject != null)
        {
            if (RemotingInterface != null && RemotingInterface.WinCalServerFound)
            {
                RemotingInterface.WinCalCloseConnection();
            }

            if (Marshal.IsComObject(RemotingClassObject))
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(RemotingClassObject);
            }

            RemotingClassObject = null;
        }

        // Perform garbage collection
        GC.Collect(); // collects all unused memory
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); // wait until GC has finished its work
        GC.Collect();
    }
    #endregion Public Methods

    #region Private Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Attempt the COM Server option
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectToServer"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IWinCalClient TryLoadComServer(bool connectToServer)
    {
        if (RemotingClassObject != null)
        {
            UnloadClient();
        }

        foreach (Guid clsId in ClassIdList)
        {
            try
            {
                RemotingClassObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(clsId, true));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (RemotingClassObject != null)
            {
                RemotingInterface = (IWinCalClient)RemotingClassObject;

                if (RemotingInterface == null)
                {
                    UnloadClient();
                    continue;
                }

                if (CanClientConnect(_RemotingInterface, connectToServer))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (Marshal.IsComObject(RemotingClassObject))
            {
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(RemotingClassObject);
            }

            RemotingClassObject = null;
        }

        return RemotingInterface;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determine whether the client and server versions are compatible
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="client"></param>
    /// <param name="connectToServer">If true, the interface will not close the server connection after connecting to verify compatibility</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool CanClientConnect(IWinCalClient client, bool connectToServer)
    {
        bool serverConnected = client.WinCalOpenServer(WinCalServerName, WinCalServerPort) && client.WinCalServerFound;

        // If it isn't compatible and the client connected to the server, close the connection
        if (serverConnected && !connectToServer)
        {
            client.WinCalCloseConnection();
        }

        return serverConnected;
    }
    #endregion Private Methods
}
```

**The line, "*RemotingInterface = (IWinCalClient)RemotingClassObject;*" fails for the .NET Framework case.**

Comment: Why would you need to go via COM? .NET Framework and .NET Core and .NET 5 should be able to interoperate directly

Comment: No-one is going to download random files from Dropbox and run and test the,. Please distill your question into a [mcve] and explain what exactly is not working

Comment: @Charlieface, nobody has to download anything. They only need to view all of it. I provided a link to the folder with all of the solutions that is a minimal reproducible sample. And I did explain exactly what isn't working. It doesn't work to obtain the COM Interop interface from a .NET Framework COM Interop server like I can from a .NET Core (.NET 5) COM Interop server.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot get it to work for the .NET Framework COM Interop assembly"? What exactly in your test code doesn't work?

Comment: Hi,  @SimonMourier . Above you can see that the call, "RemotingInterface = (IWinCalClient)RemotingClassObject;" fails for the .NET Framework case, but not for the .NET 5 case.

Comment: How do you test that with your sample

Comment: @SimonMourier I run the ClientLoaderTestApp solution and click the "Load" button. For the .NET Framework case, it fails at the line I mentioned. Of course, the .NET 5 COM server needs to be registered using regsvr32 and the .NET Framework sample needs to be registered using regasm before running the sample.

Comment: @SimonMourier, It's necessary to set a breakpoint and step through the code to see the behavior.

Comment: The problem you have in this case (once registration is ok, your server class id is F685826A-5222-4615-BA80-0C38D5C6A036, not defined in the client as you posted it, PS you should use github, not dropbox) is `"System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'CMI.WinCalRemoting.cWinCalClient' to type 'CMI.WinCalRemoting.IWinCalClient'.` which is expected. You can't call .NET Framework From .NET Framework using COM. .NET framework just sees the .NET classes exactly as what they are. What you can do is share a common .NET assembly and classes between the two projects.

Comment: Ahhh! @SimonMourier, thanks for that information. And, yes, I have to apologize that I was using the test app to test the real implementation, which has that CLSID that doesn't match the one in the sample. So, does this mean I can get the interface for the .NET Framework COM server from within a .NET 5 assembly?

Comment: @SimonMourier, But I can't add a reference to a .NET Framework assembly for a .NET 5 assembly and vice versa.

Comment: Yes you can. With your sample, you must 1) create a "common" .NET framework (4.7.2) assembly 2) put IWinCalClient.cs in it 3) remove IWinCalClient.cs from all other projects (.NET fx and .NET5+) and 4) reference "common.dll" from all other projects. Another solution is to create a .TLB (not from .NET) and build an interop assembly from this common.TLB, and don't use common.dll at all.

Comment: @SimonMourier, I'm not fully understanding because the "common" shared assembly has to be either a .NET 5 or a .NET Framework assembly to be referenced by one or the other. And, regarding the "legacy" .,NET Framework client, it can't be changed since these old versions of the server app are already in the field.

I also tried to instantiate the .NET Framework client form a .NET Core test app and it won't even instantiate.

Comment: @SimonMourier, if I did want to implement a true COM interop server for the legacy .NET Framework version of the client, how would I go about that? Do you have a link? Also, how do I share my code via Git-Hub?

Comment: Referencing a .NET Framework assembly from a .NET Core/5+ assembly works fine. As for the rest, your questions seems too wide or too related to your context to be able to be answered on this site.

Comment: @SimonMourier, OK, I'm a dummy. Seriously. In the past, I had only tried to reference a .NET Framework PROJECT, not an assembly. But it works just fine. This resolves all of the issues I thought I had. I REALLY appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @SimonMourier, correction. After actually trying the approach of referencing a .NET 5 assembly from a .NET Framework, app solution, it wouldn't run because it couldn't resolve the .NET 5 runtime. This is no problem for .NET Framework client solutions, but for .NET Core client apps, I have no way of instantiating the COM class from the legacy .NET Framework COM server. I'll have to try to figure out how to make the .NET Framework COM implementation behave like a true COM server like the .NET 5 COM server does.